# How Main.storyboard and ViewController.swift tied in an empty iOS project?

Tags: ios, swift

When I create an empty project in Xcode 7, there are some swift files and storyboard by default. The Main.storyboard and ViewController.swift are tied to each other but how? I looked for it on Info.plist but could not figure that out.

Comment: open storyboard as xml and try to decipher the info. This xml will be parsed before compilation by the XCode IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storyboard contains that information.

[image]

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. I just found that.